# Get better binarized image

Tags: image-processing, matlab

There is [an example](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2016/07/25/adaptive-thresholding-for-binarization/?s_eid=PSM_da) of adaptive binarization in a MATLAB Blog.

**(1) Input** : image sourced from [linked article](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2016/07/25/adaptive-thresholding-for-binarization/?s_eid=PSM_da).

[image]

So I tried `LocalAdaptiveBinarize` in order to reproduce:

```
pic = Import[
  "http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/files/bradley_method_01.png"]
LocalAdaptiveBinarize[ImageCrop[pic], 100]
```

**(2) Result** :

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But as we see, the result is much worser than MATLAB's:

[image]

Is there a better method?

Comment: `LocalAdaptiveBinarize[ImageCrop[pic], 50]` is better already. What did you try? Using the additional parameters (see help) will get you even better results, so go ahead and experiment.

Comment: @YvesKlett I don't think the 50 is enough.I think maybe we sholud get is [threshold image](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/files/bradley_method_04.png) firstly.the `TopHatTransform` maybe can help a little.

Comment: well, did you try that already?

Comment: Slightly related: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1932/

Comment: @nikie Thanks a lot.

Comment: @yode VC.one's edit looked wrong on my computer, so I tried to fix it.  But now I think it was my internet that was messing things up.  Oh well, I tried to do what was intended, but on imgur, the site's image host.  Roll back if you like....

Comment: @MichaelE2 It don't change my original target.Thanks for your attention. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you seen that [`LocalAdaptiveBinarize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocalAdaptiveBinarize.html) has some more possible arguments?

```
LocalAdaptiveBinarize[pic, 4.5, {.72, .55, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow,I have not noted it before this.

Answer (score 6):

We can use the highpass filter:

```
hp = HighpassFilter[pic, 0.12]
Binarize[hp, 0.01]
```

with the result

[image]

For comparison, that is what one can achieve with `Photoshop` without using any local adjustments

[image]

Of course, manual local adjustments can make wonders!